# How to reverse content spinning

Tags: php, python, mysql, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to create a tool that can reverse a content spin.

**You can see below what is content spinning :**

```
{Max|He} {taps|raps|thumps|drums} his {pencil|pen|finger} {against|on} {his|the} {desk|table|writing desk} and {chews|chews on|gnaws on} gum {when|while} {he’s|he is} {bored|tired|lazy}.
```

[image]

1. RED : “Max thumps his finger on his desk and gnaws on gum when he is lazy.”
2. BLUE : “He raps his pencil against the table and chews on gum while he is tired.”

---

**The problem :**

Imagine I have 500 results in my database, how can I reverse this 500 results to make one **spin sentence** like this ?

*{Max|He} {taps|raps|thumps|drums} his {pencil|pen|finger} {against|on} {his|the} {desk|table|writing desk} and {chews|chews on|gnaws on} gum {when|while} {he’s|he is} {bored|tired|lazy}.*

Thank's for your time !

Comment: well - the first step would be creating *all* 10368 results (which is trivial), the second would be to feed them in a sophisticated pattern recognition algorithm (which is far outside the scope of SO)

Answer (score 1):

With postgresql:

```
create TABLE tbl (c TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl(c)
VALUES  ('Max taps his pencil')
  ,('Max raps his pencil')
  ,('Max raps his drums')
  ,('Max raps his drums pencil')
;

SELECT nr, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT elem) FROM (
  SELECT
    elem,
    row_number()
    OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS nr
  FROM (SELECT
          id,
          regexp_split_to_table(c, ' ') AS elem
        FROM tbl) x
) a GROUP BY nr;
```

Returns:

```
1,{Max}
2,{raps,taps}
3,{his}
4,{drums,pencil}
5,{pencil}
```

Join result for answer

```
SELECT string_agg(
    CASE WHEN 2 > array_length(w,1) THEN w[1]::TEXT
                                    ELSE '{'||array_to_string(w,'|')||'}'
    END
    ,' ') FROM (SELECT nr, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT elem) as w FROM (
  SELECT
    elem,
    row_number()
    OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS nr
  FROM (SELECT
          id,
          regexp_split_to_table(c, ' ') AS elem
        FROM tbl) x
) a GROUP BY nr ORDER BY nr
) b
;
```

Retuns: `Max {raps|taps} his {drums|pencil} pencil`

Php solution:

```
/*Read this from database*/
$in = array('Max taps his pencil'
  ,'Max raps his pencil'
  ,'Max raps his drums'
  ,'Max raps his drums pencil');

$statWordsAtIndex = [];

$addWordAtIndex = function ($word,$index) use (&$statWordsAtIndex) {
    if ( !array_key_exists($index,$statWordsAtIndex) ) {
        $statWordsAtIndex[$index] = [$word];
    }
    else if (!in_array($word,$statWordsAtIndex[$index]) ) {
        $statWordsAtIndex[$index][] = $word;
    }
};
foreach ($in as $sid => $sentence) {
    $words = explode(' ',$sentence);
    foreach ($words  as $pos => $word) {
        $addWordAtIndex($word,$pos);
    }
}
foreach ($statWordsAtIndex as $words) {
    if (2 > count($words) ) {
        echo $words[0],' ';
    }
    else {
        echo '{',implode('|',$words),'} ';
    }
}
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I my case the content are more long, the spin result content 300 words. I not sure that with work in this case.

Comment: @Pixel there is no limit on word count, a php solution woud be a better fit for you?

Comment: No, i'm not limited by the language, postgresql, python, php is it ok.

Comment: Thank's for the code. Please can you try this snippet http://pastebin.com/wYkpmhCu. The generate spin is not readable :/